Django test case is showing errors because of moesif
I do not want to push actual api key. When I replaced the actual key on code base this error is generated
E               vcr.errors.CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException: Can't overwrite existing cassette ('/app/armor_backend/users/tests/recordings/test_user_with_empty_code.yaml') in your current record mode ('once').

E               No match for the request (<Request (GET) https://api.moesif.net/v1/config>) was found.

E               Found 1 similar requests with 0 different matcher(s) :

E               

E               1 - (<Request (GET) https://api.moesif.net/v1/config>).

E               Matchers succeeded : ['uri', 'method']

E               Matchers failed :

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vcr/stubs/__init__.py:231: CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException

----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------

Unauthorized access getting application configuration. Please check your Appplication Id.

------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------

ERROR    moesifapi.controllers.base_controller:base_controller.py:41 HTTP Response not ok [response status: 401 | header: {'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Length': '153', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Date': 'Wed, 09 Feb 2022 06:18:37 GMT', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'vary': 'Origin,Accept-Encoding'} | raw_body: {"moesif_error":{"code":"auth_error","msg":"X-Moesif-Application-Id request header is invalid. Please get a valid Moesif Collector Application Id from your Moesif account"}}]

I skipped all outgoing and incoming calls from logging for testing. But still moesif is being called somehow.
Here is my test case
@vcr.use_cassette
def test_user_with_invalid_code(
    self, client, use_invalid_code
):
    response = client.post(
        self.endpoint,
        content_type="application/json",
        data=json.dumps(use_invalid_code),
    )

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

I tried to skip logging all the incoming and outgoing calls but no luck

Moesif here. Could you share your email and the config used with support@moesif.com and we can take a look? From a quick glance, it seems to be failing due to a missing or invalid Application Id. If you're dynamically loading the application id from a config file or envvar, I might suggest checking it matches the one in Moesif ensuring no extra characters added.

I have provided a wrong application id on perpose. I do not want my application id to be on github.  my initial plan was to populate the right application id from stage server. But for some reason my test case are failing  only for those few test cases where VCR cassette were used.
